# Prevent letters or keys that are not numbers from being used in input type="number" forms

Tags: javascript, validation, input

This seems like an easy question and I have asked it multiple times but I now have a whole host of answers that do and don't work and some I just plain do not understand. Then others are saying that the code I am using is deprecated. So, can this be a once and for all post please ;)

I have a form with seven inputs. Each of those seven inputs needs a number between 0 and 1000 and can have up to 3 decimal places. So, 999.999 would be accepted as would 0.001.

No letters can be accepted. No negative numbers can be accepted. Only one decimal place can be accepted.

I have a form called dzCalculator which I will call using an event listener like this:

```
document.getElementById("dzCalculator").addEventListener("keydown", validateForm)
function validateForm() {
```

I have used various "keycode" which ? etc but told all are deprecated.

So what code can I use that when a keypress is called a preventDefault() occurs that stops that keypress from actually going into the field preventing an incorrect and invalid form submission.

I already have:

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="1000" step="0.001">
```

But this is only good browser side and the MDN says this should not be the only defence you use, you should definitely use scripts. But MDN neglect to tell us what those scripts are, and for us beginners, this is a really difficult task (especially when so many answers come back with deprecated code which lends me to being told off :P )

Comment: You have to validate the input value *at the server*, is what MDN is saying. Not client-side JavaScript.

Comment: ahhh, ok, well, in this case there is no "server" - it's all just interactive frontend for this site. My real problem is this: https://gyazo.com/793135b22aee23ad2d9077a586ced7f9

When you add an incorrect value and the alert comes up, on Firefox, the alert just floats and I don't know how to stop that. It's the native Firefox alert and it is such a big bug for how the site looks and feels and it definitely detracts from UX.

Comment: @PaulDavis have you looked at the validation API to override the behavior? https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation_api.asp

Comment: @PaulDavis The flyover text for me (in Firefox) only shows up while the element has focus and the mouse cursor is over it. HTML form validation is designed to work without JavaScript; its behaviors really have almost nothing to do with JavaScript.

Comment: Yes, I know that the validation can be HTML based, but the issue is that fly over text, it is awful. If I can stop it happening, then I will just use HTML based input limitations. I am fine with that as everything is front end.

Answer (score 1):

Just detecting keystrokes is not as useful as you'd think, remember you can still paste from clipboard. I wouldn't spend much time with this since client-side validation is just a commodity for the user and HTML+CSS can handle most of it. At most I'd add some fallback JavaScript to validate on submission:

```js
document.getElementById("dzCalculator").addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
   if (!document.querySelector('input[type="number"]').validity.valid) {
       event.preventDefault();
       alert("Invalid input, aborting submission");
   } else {
       alert("Everything's fine");
   }
});
```

```css
input[type="number"] + div {
    display: none;
}
input[type="number"]:valid {
    background-color: #C4ECC7;
}
input[type="number"]:invalid {
    background-color: #EAC6C6;
}
input[type="number"]:invalid + div {
    display: block;
    color: #C66464; 
}
```

```html
<form id="dzCalculator">
  <div>Number between 0 and 1000 and can have up to 3 decimal places:</div>
  <input type="number" min="0" max="1000" step="0.001">
  <div>Invalid number</div>
  <div><input type="submit" value="Submit"></div>
</form>
```

If you have some rules that cannot be expressed in raw HTML attributes, you may want to check them by adding an event listener for the input's `change` event.

Comment: This is perfect and works like a charm... except (sorry) https://gyazo.com/0d870bb94b4c6ac24a45eeb6d2b57c9d

This is the exact thing I am trying to avoid because on Firefox, this alert floats and it really detracts from the UX. If I can stop that alert happening, your validation method is beautiful!

Comment: Would be good if I could add this line into it too:

` document.getElementById("submitCalculation").setAttribute("disabled","disabled"); `

Comment: I go from one problem to another. I have an <input type="reset"... that is not displaying now either when using this code. It is the CSS preventing it, but now I can not work out what code to use to get the CSS to show. 

https://gyazo.com/6b6eb545bd518be3ec60e324b1234414

:( I seem to move one step forward and 5 back

Comment: Well, that's how Firefox UI works. It's good that it doesn't disappear on scroll though I admit it should probably follow the control. As about the reset button, my HTML and CSS structure was just a quick example for the runnable snippet.

Comment: I fixed the reset button by d-block in the parent div. It's fine.

Answer (score 0):

Managing input into interfaces has never been a real concern for W3C. Web pages are above all made to transmit information, on a very large scale; not to manage data entry issues (This means that on a numeric keypad, a `,` is entered, because keyboards take the value of the client computer's country system into account).

In your case, I would point out that in other countries, the decimal point is a comma, even if the value in memory must be kept with a period.

Your input control for keyboard input (and not for form validation, as the W3C has defined with the use of a patern) represents a large amount of code: you must check the value entered and where it enters in the entry already present, and settle any conflicts, example: should entering a new decimal point be considered as a displacement of the decimal point, and in this case, the excess digits to the right or on the left should they be truncated, or rounded, or imply a refusal?

With the arrival of nodeJS things may have changed, but far from being mature (eg entering dates); we can also look for various solutions in github libraries (or elsewhere), but we must be prepared for great frustrations on this subject.

Comment: I hear you! Definitely! This is a major frustration, and something so simple that should be able to be implemented in HTML. There's a good solution above, but in Firefox it leads to a real poor user experience https://gyazo.com/0d870bb94b4c6ac24a45eeb6d2b57c9d

I am just not satisfied using that code to have that appear on my site when I submit it :(

Comment: @PaulDavis  I also proposed an interface management for entering a PIN code, if that inspires you? see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63633918/enabling-4-digit-pincode-autofill-using-cookies/63663449#63663449